# Why is the setInterval function not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

It keeps showing the error message that it is an infinite loop. I am only beggining to learn React, and this is a Clicker game. How do I change my code to make the setInterval work. Thank you.(BTW I do not want any other changes to the code that won't affect the setInterval function. And yes, I have used setInterval in many projects already and it worked out fine.)

````
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  let [add, setAdd] = useState(1);
  let [numC, setNumC] = useState(0);
  let [numCP, setNumCP] = useState(10);
  let [numW, setNumW] = useState(0);
  let [numWP, setNumWP] = useState(20)
  setInterval(setNum(num+=numW),3000);
  const click = () => {
    setNum((num += add));
  };
  const clicker = () => {
    if (num >= numCP) {
      setNumC((numC += 1));
      setNum((num -= numCP));
      setNumCP((numCP += 5));
      setAdd((add += 1));
    }
  };
  const worker = () => {
    if (num >= numWP) {
      setNumW((numW += 1));
      setNum((num -= numWP));
      setNumWP((numWP += 10));
    }

  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Clicker Game</h1>
      <div>
        {num}
        <button onClick={click}>Click</button>
      </div>
      <p />
      <div>
        {numC}
        <button onClick={clicker}>Buy({numCP})</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {numW}
        <button onClick={worker}>Buy({numWP})</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First you are immediately calling the `setNum` when you should be passing a callback to be executed when the interval is passed.

So `setInterval(() => setNum(num+=numW),3000);`

But now you have the second issue, each time the component is re-rendered you will initiate an additional interval. (*and it will be re-rendered a lot, at the minimum each time the interval callback is fired*)

So you would likely need to use a `useEffect`, with 0 dependencies so it runs once, if you want to set it and let it run continuously.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => setNum(num += numW), 3000);
}, []);
```

But now you will encounter yet another issue. The `num` and `numW` used in the interval will be locked to the values in the first render of the component.

For the `num` you can work around it, by using the `callback` syntax of the `setNum`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => setNum(currentNum => currentNum += numW), 3000);
}, []);
```

but `numW` will never update.

A final tool, is to reset the interval each time the `numW` or `num` changes. To do that you will need to return a function from the `useEffect` that does the clearing.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => setNum(currentNum => currentNum += numW), 3000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [numW]);
```

But this will have the minor issue that the interval is now not constant, since it resets.

Comment: @AleksandraMarusii just replace the `setInterval` line in your code with the last snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every time one of your state variables changes, the component is re-rendered, i.e. the function `App` is called again. This will call `setInterval` over and over again.

You want to look at [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to put your `setInterval`s in.